# Array type expected [compile-error]

Tags: java, arrays

Im working with the following method:

```
public void m(List<? extends Object[]> objs){
    objs.stream()
        .map(oa -> oa[0])   //compile error
                            //array type expected
        .forEach(System.out::println); 

}
```

[***DEMO***](http://ideone.com/eqMmBi)

Why doesn't it work? I thought everything that extends array can be viewed as an array. Actually I can get `length` from the array.

Comment: Downvoter, would you be so kind and explain in comments why doesn't it work? Why do I need to cast explicitly to `Object[]`?

Comment: If you change `m(List<? extends Object[]> objs)` to `m(List<Object[]> objs)` it compiles, but I'm not answering because I don't understand the implications of this change or what's wrong with your original.

Comment: @StephenP Unfotunately I cannot change the signature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is actually no such class that extends `Object[]`; each array has a fixed type and its own class, eg `MyClass[].class`

You should use a *typed* method:

```
public <T> void m(List<T[]> objs){
    objs.stream()
            .map(oa -> oa[0])   // no compile error
            .forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

Comment: Never thought abt it, but indeed `class MyClass extends Object[]{ }` does not compile.

Comment: @St.Antario arrays are a `native` impl - you can't do anything with them

Comment: @Bohemian nit it's not an implementation reason that precludes it, the forbidden by specification. (Failing to find the relevant section of JLS on my phone...)

Comment: @AndyTurner: I would say it follows from [JLS8 - 10.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8): "Although an array type is not a class, the Class object of every array acts as if:

* The direct superclass of every array type is Object."